# Is it possible to create sub-menus for Services?

Tags: macos, services

If I have several OS X Services set up for "Text," is it possible to organize them within custom-titled menus, within my systemwide selected-text context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to perform this currently.

- [Items in the Services Menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/menu.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000851-BBCDFIDD)

> The items in the Services menu are commands categorized by what type of data they operate on. The application icon of the application providing a service appears to the left of the service’s name in the menu. If two or more applications provide a service with an identical name, the name of the application providing each one is appended in parentheses after the name of the service in the menu.
>
> The Services menu is populated when the menu is opened.

I suppose you could hack the OS (assuming SIP is not enabled) to add that functionality, but it's not something that's publicly available or documented widely that a private API exists to do what you ask.